# How to sort by date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to perform the following query in mysql.

```
SELECT 
    evaluationpart.id,
    evaluationpart.creation,
    evaluationpart.evaluationid,
    evaluationpart.partid,
    evaluation.horimeter,
    personcompressorpart.hourcapacity,
    evaluation.evaluationdate AS changedate,
    evaluation.averageworkload,
    @ed := DATEDIFF(curdate(), evaluation.evaluationdate) AS elapseddays,
    @uh:= @ed * evaluation.averageworkload AS usedhours,
    @htu:= personcompressorpart.hourcapacity - @uh AS hourstouse,
    @nc:= curdate() + INTERVAL (@htu/evaluation.averageworkload) DAY AS nextchange
FROM evaluationpart
LEFT JOIN evaluation ON evaluation.id = evaluationpart.evaluationid
LEFT JOIN personcompressorpart ON personcompressorpart.id = evaluationpart.partid
ORDER BY @nc ASC
```

But the Order By is not working and I'm getting this result
[image]

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: You're abusing MySQL variables _don't do that_ because it makes it harder to reason about set-based operations. Anyway, to fix it, use `ORDER BY nextchange ASC`.

Comment: The correct way would be to repeat the query instead of storing it in a variable to use later? by the way, thanks for the reply.

Comment: You don't need to "repeat the query" at all (but you need to get used to that anyway: SQL is excessively verbose... ). I'm just saying you need to change your last-line to use the actual column-name, not a scalar variable.

Comment: I understand about the order by, but about the other variables, is it a bad practice to do it this way? I wanted to learn how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the column name in the ORDER BY clause.
If you want to order the query result by the column named 'nextchange', the ORDER BY clause should be `ORDER BY nextchange ASC`.
Here's the MySQL documentation on Sorting Rows: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html
I hope this helps.